# Crystal report providing only 7.9 inches margin

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Please Help,

Crystal report only allows horizontal width till 7 inches and a little above but i need to design a report which is to be printed on an a4 size sheet with predefined layout from the stationary.

How do i increase the crystal report size to 8.10 inches to fit all my contents.
Is there any other alternatives to crystal report with which i can achieve the required

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the size of the sheet use option in page setup.

```
File --> Page Setup --> there go to Unit --> for selected option give the size you require
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do, is just select A4 size as you want (if you need custom size , then you have to define ,other than available page size).

No as you want to print on pre-printed format. No issue with that, only that you have to manually set every report field to set to exact location of printing.

For this take a hard copy of printed material and inch-tape. Good to if actually printed invoice or bill where printed material and our billing/invoice information available of customer or any other. If no then no issue.

First of all, Check the basic margin of top-bottom-left-right and as above suggested, go to page setup and define the basic margin.

Now in report ui, check the margin in inches/cm and set the field as per .

do for each and every field to be print.

At finally you have to print a page. if it is ok , then again print with continue printing with 3 or 4 pages.